# ServiceException: Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, spreadsheet, worksheet

Hi I'm trying to insert a row in a google worksheet, but I can not do it becouse have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Method Not Allowed
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:632)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:613)
at it.unical.mat.spreadsheet.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

Please help my to resolve this problem, this is my code:

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException
{

 SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MyApp");
 FeedURLFactory factory = FeedURLFactory.getDefault();
 String key = "***my_key***";
 URL spreadSheetUrl = factory.getWorksheetFeedUrl(key,"public","full");
 WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(spreadSheetUrl, WorksheetFeed.class);

 WorksheetEntry worksheet = feed.getEntries().get(13);
 URL url = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();


 ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
 row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("header", "aaa");

 row = service.insert(url, row);
 }
}
```

My intent is to **insert a new row in a google worksheet!**

**If reading rows I don't have problems, but the problem is when write in a rows!**

Comment: exactly where in the code this ex is raised

Comment: @ZigMandel at this Line:  `row = service.insert(url, row);`